# Low Poly Character Elbow Deforming

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, shape-keys, vertex-weights

I made a low poly character that I am rigging currently.  However, when I bend the elbows inward on the Z-axis, the inner part of the elbow bends too much (Picture attached).

1. I have tried doing shape keys however I have the mirror modifier enabled so that wont work as the key effects both sides.
2. I have tried changing the weights but haven't found the right numbers.

** On the elbow there are 8 vertices that make it up, 4 on the outer part, and 4 on the inner part **

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13RwzuTDdQ_MhGH_Z18uQ_l7vIP_pelpN/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: please share your file. If shapekey doesn't work you could create one or 2 bones for the elbow so that it will deform it?

Comment: I have added a link to the file.  

Hm.  I think I saw someone talk about that.   So you think adding a bone in the elbow would help?

Comment: why not but why don't you want to apply the Mirror?

Comment: if you create an elbow bone that influence the inner side of the elbow, you can use it to deform the mesh when the arm is bent, but it means either move this elbow bone after rotating the arm or give it a driver

Comment: @moonboots I guess I could.  The only thing I didnt know is if I need to change the mesh for any reason, will reapplying the mirror still work?

Comment: you can use the Mesh > Symmetrize or Snap to Symmetry to symmetrize back but you'll have to bring correction in Weight Paint mode

Comment: @moonboots Couldnt I just reapply the mirror after I do the shape keys?

Comment: you can't apply a mirror if you ceate shapekeys

Comment: @moonbootsI see. What I ended up doing was the shape key which seems to be fine for now.  Ill just have to make sure I change each side the same which shouldn't be too bad. Thanks for the help!